# Swipe part of the page using pager view

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have `ViewPager` with `PagerTabStrip` , when swiping from page to another, both the pager and the tab will be moving together. (like google paly)

It's working fine. now all the pages have common data, and one part is going to change when swiping, so i don't want to swipe the whole page, just the area that going to change.

As you can see in the following image just the red area will be effected when swipe pages, the green area will not move.

I've searched a lot, but i can't find anything useful, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

viewpager code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#003366"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"/>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: The user will be able to swipe left/right only when swiping in the content red zone(in the area that actual changes)?

Comment: @Luksprog yes, just the red area,if the user swipe in the green area no change will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `swipeyTabs` is the answer.
The problem when using `PagerTabStrip` is that the `PagerTabStrip` will be inside the `ViewPager` tag see the following code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#003366"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"/>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

so you cant separate them form each other.
but when using the SwipeyTabs, each tag will be as a separate part, see the following code:

```
<net.peterkuterna.android.apps.swipeytabs.SwipeyTabs
        android:id="@+id/swipeytabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        swipeytabs:bottomBarColor="#ff96aa39"
        swipeytabs:bottomBarHeight="2dip"
        swipeytabs:tabIndicatorHeight="3dip"
        android:background="#ff3b3b3b"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

In this case, you can customize your layout as you want by dealing with `ViewPager` and `SwipeyTabs` as two parts.

In your case, I guess you can put the `SwipeyTabs` and `ViewPager` in red position like in the image, and in the green areas, you have to just adjust them as your needs.

I found these links which may help you. Good luck with that.

- [Swipey tabs sample](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/browse/trunk/SwipeyTabsSample/#SwipeyTabsSample%253Fstate%253Dclosed)
- [ViewPager meets Swipey Tabs](http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I misread your post. Separating the `ViewPager` from the `PagerTabStrip` may not work or may need another approach. I'll leave the answer here in case it may help anyway.

You can achieve that by embedding the `ViewPager` in a separate fragment and placing another independent fragment beneath, which is not controlled by the `ViewPager`.

Basically, your main activity consists of two fragments: one that contains the `ViewPager` (which contains more fragments), another one that contains your fixed view.

To do it properly, this needs support for nested fragments, which is only available on Android 4.2 or otherwise in the latest support library (revision 11).

Be aware when instantiating your adapter for the `ViewPager`, you need to use the `FragmentManager` returned by `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: the application should be working on 2.3.3 and above. but i'm going to try what you suggest. and thanks for your help.

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss Android 2.3.3 shouldn't be a problem with the support library. The split layout (PagerTabStrip separated) may be tricky.

Comment: thanks for your help, even if your answer didn't solve the problem, i think it's going to guide me to a good solution, and thanks again :)